# getting transaction id before checkout in woo commerce

Tags: woocommerce, transactions, checkout

I have a mobile gateway integration, according to the docs the TransactionID has to incremented with each request and is an Integer.
• Calculate hash for token . Can use both MD5 and SHA_256 it is recommended
to use SHA_256 for security as it does not easily generate collisions.
• Token version 1
MD5(transactionID+amount+itemdetails+”merchantsecret”))
• Token version 2
SHA_256(transactionID+amount+itemdetails+
”merchantsecret”+responseCode))
• Client key string is a secret key given by Vodafone.
• Receive response with URL for payments gateway, requestID, token,
responseCode, tokenv2.

i am using  woo commerce how will this be possible

Comment: How can there be a "transactionID" before checkout.?

Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] and people will be very glad to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.